# Filter with params in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need a tip of how to deal with a kind of filter.

In a controller, I know how to map a URL with a variable.
Something like this, for example:

```
@GetMapping("/something/{id}")
public ...{
...
}
```

How Can I change the mapping above for filter the URL with 
explicit params? Something like:

http://localhost:8080/something**?id=1**

thank you all.

Comment: `void getMethod(@QueryParam("id") String id)`

Comment: /something/1 I know how to do. I just need to set as the code above. @Mapping("/something/{id}")  deals with the "/something/1" . What I want is the filter with the question mark. Something like "/something?id=1"

Comment: thank you two. I am going to test the query param

Answer (score 2):

`@RequestParam` to extract query parameters

```
@GetMapping("/api/foos")
@ResponseBody
public String getFoos(@RequestParam String id) {
    return "ID: " + id;
}
```

In this example, we used @RequestParam to extract the id query parameter.

A simple GET request would invoke getFoos:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/foos?id=abc
----
ID: abc
```

[here more info](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param)